# Correct approach to handle react-routes on a server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, react-router

I have uploaded my application to the server and encountered a problem.

going to example.com displays homepage correctly, however after doing something like example.com/dashboard I get an error `Cannot GET /dashboard`. I assume this is because server is actually trying to get that path, but it still needs to go through `index.html` as this is a single page app using react-router. I believe I need to redirect all requests to got to index.html to make this work, but I'm not sure how I can implement this. I am using express to server my files, here is my server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port: ' + 8080);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up Express so that if a request *is not* for a static file it falls through and is handled as a frontend route by your React app on `index.html`.

Adding to your above example, something like this,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.path.startsWith('/static')) return next()
  res.sendFile('dist/index.html')
})

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port: ' + 8080);
});
```

Notice that I added the `/static` path for your static assets. That means every request for a static asset by your app has to look like `/static/foo.jpg` (or whatever). It might be worth renaming your `dist` folder `static` too, to keep names in sync.

This is a useful pattern because it lets you easily differentiate between a request for a static asset, and a request that should fall through to your frontend app.